# Learning to work with data in python

Tags: python, parsing, csv, numpy, pandas

I am attempting to write something that will parse the results of Keno draws.  Keno is a lottery where 20 numbers are drawn out of a pool of 80 numbers and players pick between 1 and 10 numbers per draw and try to match as many as possible.

I thought it would be a fun learning exercise to load in a large number of draw results and see how close the posted odds for a number being drawn are.  Maybe even do 2, 3 ... 10 number combinations and see how they stack up against the posted odds.  I realize that even with 250,000 draws it is a small sample size but it's more for my python education and not for anything else.

My question is what python modules should I be looking at learning?  Pandas, Numpy etc.

The draws are stored in a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

For python, there is something called the [pydata](http://pydata.org/) stack.

This often refers to [scipy/numpy](http://www.scipy.org/), [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) among other packages.

Pandas does [read csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) files fairly well. But I won't say it's easy. I base that statement on that about half the questions I answer here on Stackoverflow is about this particular function.

That being said, I see no questions about any other package in the [pydata](http://pydata.org/) stack that parses CSV, so it's fairly safe to assume, **this is how people do it in python.**

I would recommend you start out with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: `numpy.loadtxt` and the [csv package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) are routinely used to read CSV packages without pandas.

Comment: @rjonnal: I believe you. My answer is very subjective, but the question has kind of no real concrete answer either so.